How to run animation of a single object on click trigger in blender?
I am developing a blender environment of a restaurant with multiple objects like fridge, curtains etc. Each of them have some animations on them. I want to play a single animation like of a fridge opening, but the whole timeline plays. Is it Animation nodes what i am missing here?

Animation in Blenders play "all" or "nothing".
But...you can mute channels in the graph editor:

By clicking on that checkbox, the channel won't be animated anymore.
So you could set mute/unmute on quick favorite, then select your objects which shouldn't be animated, select all channels -> mute
sorry for the link, but BSE made it once again, that gifs won't upload - error > 2MB although it is < 1 MB, so here the link for explaining:
https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/mute%20animations.gif
if you wanna have a one click solution, you have to write a python script which essentially does that, what i described here how you can do that manually.

Thanks I got it. I assumed the same but was curious to know if there was any way to do that.
